# How to Add a custom Font to this TextView?

Tags: java, android, import, textview

I'm trying to add a font to a textView. I have the following code-snippet, but I'm not sure how to adapt it to my code below. Can someone help me?

[image]

**Code snippet I want to integrate into my program:**

```
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Xcelsion.ttf");  //   getActivity().getAssets() 
TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
myTextView.setTypeface(myTypeface);  //
```

**Program I want to add the font to:**

```
public class ListRingtonesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SongInfo> {

    private ArrayList<SongInfo> items;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ViewHolder> listHolder = new ArrayList<ListRingtonesAdapter.ViewHolder>();
    private int curPosition = 0;
    private RingtonesSharedPreferences pref;
    private boolean inRingtones;

    static final String TAG = "LOG";

    private static final int DEFAULT_RINGTONE = 1;
    private static final int ASSIGN_TO_CONTACT = 2;
    private static final int DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION = 3;
    private static final int DEFAULT_ALARM = 4;
    private static final int DELETE_RINGTONE = 5;



    public static final String ALARM_PATH = "/media/audio/alarms/";
    public static final String ALARM_TYPE = "Alarm";
    public static final String NOTIFICATION_PATH = "/media/audio/notifications/";
    public static final String NOTIFICATION_TYPE = "Notification";
    public static final String RINGTONE_PATH = "/media/audio/ringtones/";
    public static final String RINGTONE_TYPE = "Ringtone";


    public ListRingtonesAdapter(Context context, int viewResourceId,
            ArrayList<SongInfo> objects, boolean inRingtones) {
        super(context, viewResourceId, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
        this.items = objects;
        this.pref = new RingtonesSharedPreferences(context);
        this.inRingtones = inRingtones;
        if(Main.mp.isPlaying()){
            Main.mp.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ActionItem defRingtone = new ActionItem(DEFAULT_RINGTONE,
                "Default Ringtone", context.getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.icon_ringtone));
        ActionItem assign = new ActionItem(ASSIGN_TO_CONTACT,
                "Contact Ringtone", context.getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.icon_contact));
        ActionItem defNotifi = new ActionItem(DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION,
                "Default Notification", context.getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.icon_notify));
        ActionItem defAlarm = new ActionItem(DEFAULT_ALARM, "Default Alarm",
                context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_alarm));


        final QuickAction mQuickAction = new QuickAction(context);

        mQuickAction.addActionItem(defRingtone);
        mQuickAction.addActionItem(assign);
        mQuickAction.addActionItem(defNotifi);
        mQuickAction.addActionItem(defAlarm);


        // setup the action item click listener
        mQuickAction
                .setOnActionItemClickListener(new QuickAction.OnActionItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(QuickAction quickAction, int pos,
                            int actionId) {
                        switch (actionId) {
                        case DEFAULT_RINGTONE:
                            setDefaultRingtone(items.get(curPosition));
                            Toast.makeText(context,
                                    "Ringtone set successfully",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        case ASSIGN_TO_CONTACT:
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context,
                                    SelectContactActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("position", curPosition);
                            context.startActivity(intent);
                            break;
                        case DEFAULT_ALARM:
                            setDefaultAlarm(items.get(curPosition));
                            Toast.makeText(context,
                                    "Alarm set successfully",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        case DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION:
                            setDefaultNotice(items.get(curPosition));
                            Toast.makeText(context,
                                    "Notification set successfully",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                });

        // setup on dismiss listener, set the icon back to normal
        mQuickAction.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss() {
            }
        });

        View view = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = li.inflate(R.layout.listelement, null);
            final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSongName);
            holder.btnFavorite = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btnFavorite);
            holder.btnPlayPause = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btnPlayPause);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            // holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        final SongInfo item = items.get(position);
        if (item != null) {
            final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            holder.txtName.setText(item.getName())
            ;
            if (item.isFavorite()) {
                holder.btnFavorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_favorite);
            } else {
                holder.btnFavorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_favorite_off);
            }

            if (!item.isPlaying()) {
                holder.btnPlayPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
            } else {
                holder.btnPlayPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_pause);
            }

            holder.btnPlayPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if (Main.mp.isPlaying()) {
                        Main.mp.stop();
                    }

                    for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++){
                        if(items.get(i) != item)
                            items.get(i).setPlaying(false);
                    }
                    for(int i = 0; i < listHolder.size(); i++){
                        listHolder.get(i).btnPlayPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
                    }

                    if (item.isPlaying()) {
                        holder.btnPlayPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
                        item.setPlaying(false);
                        items.get(position).setPlaying(false);
                        if (Main.mp.isPlaying()) {
                            Main.mp.stop();
                        }

                    } else {
                        curPosition = position;
                        playAudio(context, item.getAudioResource());

                        holder.btnPlayPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_pause);
                        item.setPlaying(true);
                        items.get(position).setPlaying(true);
                    }
                    for (ViewHolder object : listHolder) {
                        if (object != holder) {
                            object.btnPlayPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            holder.btnFavorite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (item.isFavorite()) {
                        holder.btnFavorite
                                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_favorite_off);
                        item.setFavorite(false);
                        pref.setString(item.getFileName(), false);
                        if (!inRingtones) {
                            Intent broadcast = new Intent();
                            broadcast.setAction("REMOVE_SONG");
                            context.sendBroadcast(broadcast);
                        }

                    } else {
                        holder.btnFavorite
                                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_favorite);
                        item.setFavorite(true);
                        pref.setString(item.getFileName(), true);
                    }
                }
            });

            listHolder.add(holder);

            view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mQuickAction.show(v);
                    curPosition = position;
                }
            });
        }

        return view;
    }

    private Object getAssets() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private TextView findViewById(int txtsongname) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView txtName;
        private ImageView btnFavorite;
        private ImageView btnPlayPause;
    }

    private void playAudio(Context context, int id) {
        if (Main.mp.isPlaying()) {
            Main.mp.stop();
        }
        Main.mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, id);
        Main.mp.setOnCompletionListener(playCompletionListener);
        Main.mp.start();
        onRingtonePlay.onPlay();
    }

    private OnCompletionListener playCompletionListener = new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++){
                items.get(i).setPlaying(false);
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < listHolder.size(); i++){
                listHolder.get(i).btnPlayPause
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
            }
        }
    };

    private void setRingtone(SongInfo info, boolean ringtone, boolean alarm,
            boolean music, boolean notification) {

        File dir = null;
        String what = null;
        if (ringtone) {
            what = "Ringtones";
        }else if(alarm){
            what = "alarms";
        }else if(notification){
            what = "notifications";
        }else{
            what = "Ringtones";
        }


        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),what);
        } else {
            dir = context.getCacheDir();
        }

        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        File file = new File(dir, info.getFileName());
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {

                InputStream inputStream = context.getResources()
                        .openRawResource(info.getAudioResource());

                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;

                while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE));

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file.getAbsolutePath());

        String[] projection = new String[] { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION

        };
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + " = \"" + file.getAbsolutePath()+ "\"", null, null);

        String strRingtone = null, strAlarm = null, strNotifi = null, strMusic = null;
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            strRingtone = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE));
            strAlarm = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM));
            strNotifi = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION));
            strMusic = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC));
        }

        if (ringtone) {
            if ((strAlarm != null) && (strAlarm.equals("1")))
                alarm = true;
            if ((strNotifi != null) && (strNotifi.equals("1")))
                notification = true;
            if ((strMusic != null) && (strMusic.equals("1")))
                music = true;

        } else if (notification) {
            if ((strAlarm != null) && (strAlarm.equals("1")))
                alarm = true;
            if ((strRingtone != null) && (strRingtone.equals("1")))
                ringtone = true;
            if ((strMusic != null) && (strMusic.equals("1")))
                music = true;

        } else if (alarm) {
            if ((strNotifi != null) && (strNotifi.equals("1")))
                notification = true;
            if ((strRingtone != null) && (strRingtone.equals("1")))
                ringtone = true;
            if ((strMusic != null) && (strMusic.equals("1")))
                music = true;

        } else if (music) {
            if ((strNotifi != null) && (strNotifi.equals("1")))
                notification = true;
            if ((strRingtone != null) && (strRingtone.equals("1")))
                ringtone = true;
            if ((strAlarm != null) && (strAlarm.equals("1")))
                alarm = true;
        }

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, info.getName());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, file.length());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
        if (ringtone) {
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, ringtone);
        } else if (notification) {
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, notification);
        } else if (alarm) {
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, alarm);
        } else if (music) {
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, music);
        }

        context.getContentResolver().delete(uri,MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + " = \"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
        Uri newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

        int type = RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALL;
        if (ringtone)
            type = RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE;
        if (alarm)
            type = RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM;
        if (notification)
            type = RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION;

        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, type, newUri);
    }

    private void setDefaultRingtone(SongInfo info) {

        File dir = null;
        String what = "Ringtones";
        Uri newUri = null;
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        boolean isRingTone = false;
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),what);
        } else {
            dir = context.getCacheDir();
        }

        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        File file = new File(dir, info.getFileName());
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {

                InputStream inputStream = context.getResources()
                        .openRawResource(info.getAudioResource());

                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;

                while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE));

        String[] columns = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, 
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE
                };

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA+" = '"+file.getAbsolutePath()+"'",null, null);
        if (cursor!=null) {
            int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int fileColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

            int ringtoneColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String audioFilePath = cursor.getString(fileColumn);
                if (cursor.getString(ringtoneColumn)!=null && cursor.getString(ringtoneColumn).equals("1")) {
                    Uri hasUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(audioFilePath);
                    newUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(hasUri, cursor.getString(idColumn));
                    isRingTone = true;
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        if (isRingTone) {
            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
        }else{
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, info.getName());
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, file.length());
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
            newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
        }
    }

    private void setDefaultAlarm(SongInfo info) {

        File dir = null;
        String what = "alarms";
        Uri newUri = null;
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        boolean isRingTone = false;
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),what);
        } else {
            dir = context.getCacheDir();
        }

        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        File file = new File(dir, info.getFileName());
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {

                InputStream inputStream = context.getResources()
                        .openRawResource(info.getAudioResource());

                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;

                while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE));

        String[] columns = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, 
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM
                };

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA+" = '"+file.getAbsolutePath()+"'",null, null);
        if (cursor!=null) {
            int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int fileColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

            int ringtoneColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String audioFilePath = cursor.getString(fileColumn);
                if (cursor.getString(ringtoneColumn)!=null && cursor.getString(ringtoneColumn).equals("1")) {
                    Uri hasUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(audioFilePath);
                    newUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(hasUri, cursor.getString(idColumn));
                    isRingTone = true;
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        if (isRingTone) {
            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM, newUri);
        }else{
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, info.getName());
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, file.length());
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
            newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM, newUri);
        }
    }

    private void setDefaultNotice(SongInfo info) {

        File dir = null;
        String what = "notifications";
        Uri newUri = null;
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        boolean isRingTone = false;
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),what);
        } else {
            dir = context.getCacheDir();
        }

        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        File file = new File(dir, info.getFileName());
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {

                InputStream inputStream = context.getResources()
                        .openRawResource(info.getAudioResource());

                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;

                while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE));

        String[] columns = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, 
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION
                };

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA+" = '"+file.getAbsolutePath()+"'",null, null);
        if (cursor!=null) {
            int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int fileColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

            int ringtoneColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String audioFilePath = cursor.getString(fileColumn);
                if (cursor.getString(ringtoneColumn)!=null && cursor.getString(ringtoneColumn).equals("1")) {
                    Uri hasUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(audioFilePath);
                    newUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(hasUri, cursor.getString(idColumn));
                    isRingTone = true;
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        if (isRingTone) {
            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION, newUri);
        }else{
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, info.getName());
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, file.length());
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
            newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION, newUri);
        }
    }

    private void deleteRingtone(SongInfo info) {
        File dir = null;
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "Ringtones");
        } else {
            dir = context.getCacheDir();
        }

        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "dir:"+dir.getPath());

        File file = new File(dir, info.getFileName());
        Log.d(TAG, "file name:"+info.getFileName());

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file
                .getAbsolutePath());

        context.getContentResolver().delete(
                uri,
                MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + " = \"" + file.getAbsolutePath()
                        + "\"", null);
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
    }

    OnRingtonePlay onRingtonePlay;
    /**
     * @param onRingtonePlay the onRingtonePlay to set
     */
    public void setOnRingtonePlay(OnRingtonePlay onRingtonePlay) {
        this.onRingtonePlay = onRingtonePlay;
    }
    interface OnRingtonePlay{
        public void onPlay();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are lots of people here willing to help, but you can't just post your whole code and ask someone to fix it for you. Please try to better understand the tools you have to use and read here on how to [make good questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and also how to write a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the font on the TextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888508/how-to-change-the-font-on-the-textview)

Comment: Are you trying to change the text in the ViewHolder? You have to extend the class .. see [Unable to add custom font in RecyclerView.ViewHolder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837181/unable-to-add-custom-font-in-recyclerview-viewholder)

Comment: @giusti, I think your assessment of what the poster is asking for is premature. It's not a request to write the whole program or even to reverse-engineer a lot of code, they're merely asking a technical question about how to set a font and provided good focused examples. It's not an outrageous request or that far out of scope. Well intentioned people in the community can easily help this beginner tackle a problem like that.

Comment: Do you disagree that this question would be much better if OP posted a minimal example instead of the code for their whole interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put typeface coding in getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) method in this part of your code

```
    View view = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = li.inflate(R.layout.listelement, null);

        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSongName);
        holder.btnFavorite = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btnFavorite);
        holder.btnPlayPause = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btnPlayPause);
        Typeface myTypeface =  Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),         "fonts/Xcelsion.ttf"); 
        holder.txtName.setTypeface(myTypeface);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        // holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Set Font Method */
public static void overrideFonts(final Context context, final View v) {
    try {
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
                overrideFonts(context, child);
            }
        } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Xcelsion.ttf"));
        }
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}

/* And use this method as below */
overrideFonts(context, myTextView);
```